# Отличие Cyrillic_General_CI_AS от SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS?

Tags: sql-server, collation

Подскажите, кто разбирается в коллейшинах БД для MSSQL Server. Чем принципиально отличается коллейшин Cyrillic_General_CI_AS от SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS?

Comment: В них, как минимум, отличаются правила сортировки для не-unicode символов.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что как раз сортировка у них одинаковая, т.к. окончание одно и тоже CI_AS: 
AS показывает, что диакритические знаки учитываются (AccentSensitivity)

Comment: Сравните как сортируются пробел, апостроф и дефис: `SELECT Ch FROM (VALUES (' '), (''''), ('-')) T(Ch) ORDER BY Ch COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS` и `SELECT Ch FROM (VALUES (' '), (''''), ('-')) T(Ch) ORDER BY Ch COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS`. Плюс, на самом деле, ещё для пары десятков спец. символов есть отличия. Но если использовать unicode (`VALUES (N' '), (N''''), (N'-')`), то разницы не будет.

Comment: Вообще же, если выбирать, то *Cyrillic_General_100_CI_AS* более актуальная, чем *Cyrillic_General_CI_AS*. А все, что с префиксом `SQL_` - для совместимости с очень старыми версиями.